# Digital Ocean Droplet blocking output of Spring Endpoint Producing Text Event Stream

Tags: java, spring, digital-ocean, spring-webflux

I have an end point in a Spring Boot application that produces Text Event Stream as output.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<EventMessage<?>> findStream() {
    return eventStream.log().share();
}
```

When running project jar locally this endpoint works fine but when I deploy this in kubernetes on a digital ocean droplet, this endpoint does not seem to respond.

I have debugged a bit, it seems when hitting the end point from browser the page keeps on loading with no data. But the request is sent as I have logs and also when a new event is published the logs appear. But not result is appearing in browser

The service is running in a single node microk8s environment deployed as NodePort

**UPDATE:**
It seems the output stream is blocked by the node's firewall as i can curl the endpoint while inside node. Still not sure how it is getting blocked.

Comment: there could be a 100 reasons as to why this doesn't work, proxies in between, how the kuberneetes clusters proxies are configured etc. etc.

Comment: It's a single node microk8s cluster. The service type is NodePort, If any additional information helps I can provide.

Comment: If you can access your endpoint inside the cluster this means that something else is blocking it as you said. Please check the firewall rules in your droplet (`ufw status`,`ufw allow NODEPORT/tcp` and/or look in the dashboard for Firewalls. Please let me know if you've managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has **nothing to do with your Cloud Provider** - Digital Ocean.

The `Block malicious downloads` feature prevents the HTML5 feature **Server Sent Events** (SSE) from working properly. As the SSE works over HTTP using text/event-stream as content-type it looks like a `never-ending download`. The scanner holds the SSE message until the channel breaks for some reason and hands over the message to the browser.

Just like you are able to cURL the endpoint while inside node, you can cURL from outside the K8S environment too.

One workaround (as suggested [here](https://community.sophos.com/products/endpoint-security-control/f/sophos-endpoint-software/74878/server-sent-events-blocked-by-download-scanner)) is to add a website authorization for the source IP of the stream.

There is also a similar [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18923) which talks about breaking of Http streaming.